# My PHP-cUrl request works in Postman, but not on the PHP webpage

Tags: php, curl

Our homemade API responds in Postman, but it doesn't in our actual webpage. The cUrl code has been literally copied from Postman, so i don't understand why it wouldn't work. We supply a token that is generated with each login.

Postman:
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wyvje.png)

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost:8080/API/Measurement/GetAll.php',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'access_token: 7ebc27863e12745fcf9157f429d07e71'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

A JSON is returned with the required data from our MySQL database.

PHPStorm: [PHPStorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooY74.png)

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost:8080/API/Measurement/GetAll.php',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 3,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      'access_token'=>$_COOKIE['access_token']
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
echo '<script>console.log("' . $response . '")</script>';

if (curl_errno($curl)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($curl);
}
curl_close($curl);

if (isset($error_msg)) {
    echo '<script>console.log("' . $error_msg . '")</script>';
}

$json = json_decode($response);
```

All that gets returned is null after the 3 second timeout is up. (I have tried without timeout, nothing happens and it times out anyway.)

Here is the code from the API itself:
[API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vChL2.png)

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/DAL/MeasurementService.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/API/headers.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/API/auth.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'GET') {
    $response = array(
        'status' => 405,
        'message' => 'Method not allowed'
    );
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit();
}

$auth_response = checkUserRole(1);
if($auth_response['status'] == 401){
    echo json_encode($auth_response);
    exit();
}

$measurements = MeasurementService::getAllMeasurements();

$response = array(
    "status" => 200,
    "data" => $measurements
);

echo json_encode($response);
exit();
?>
```

I've tried to find out why the request times out, but no luck.

I'd appreciate the help, thanks.

If any extra code is needed, feel free to ask.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved (in text form!) and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [Never post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: "in our actual webpage" implies that you have deployed somewhere else than localhost. However, your url seems to be pointing to localhost. Can you clarify this?

Comment: add CURLOPT_VERBOSE: ```$stderrh=tmpfile();
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>$stderrh));
curl_exec($ch);
/* https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76268 */
rewind($stderrh); 
$stderr=stream_get_contents($stderrh);
fclose($stderrh);
echo $stderr;
``` and show the verbose log.

Comment: @eis it is deployed on a raspberry pi. It is only intended to be accessed by members on the same network. This localhost is now running on another computer for testing purposes. I hope this clarifies your question.

Comment: @Rembie01 so are "GetAll.php" and code that you have in this question residing on the same computer with each other?

Comment: @eis indeed, that is correct.